# Form borders and title bar

Tags: forms, ms-access-2013

I'm pretty sure this must have been asked before but I can't seem to find a solution. I have some pop-up forms which I want to show without title bar since I've designed custom placement functions and I don't want them to be moved or closed from the title bar, so having it show only makes the form look uglier. I haven't found a way to hide it other than setting the form border to none, but that makes some small forms that popup on top of other forms (which I don't want to close when opening the other form because of crossed references and various visual reasons) merge with the form on the background and make it hardly distingishable.

So, I need a way to hide the form title bar while being able to set a thin border for the form to establish its bounds clearlier. I've tried setting a rectangle around my forms, but since I'm using form headers I can't put it around the whole form. I guess I could put one around the header section and another around the details section, but it makes it look horrible. Any simple way to achieve what I intend to do?

Comment: You could select the control icon and the min/max icons of the title bar to not be shown. However, I haven't ever met this requirement before, and I have been working with Access since version 1.0.

Comment: Yes, that's how I was presenting the forms before, thing is the Windows title bar makes the form look ugly and messes a bit my custom form placement and sizing functions, so I wanted to take it out while still being able to set a thin border to better define forms' boundaries.